# Mysql Procedure execute two times

Tags: php, mysql, procedure

I have the following procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE providerDistributor(IN cronHash VARCHAR(255), IN lastProccess DATETIME)
BEGIN
    SET @cronHashVar = cronHash;
    SET @lastProccess = lastProccess;

    SET @targetiDS = (SELECT `id` AS targetiDS FROM `messages_temp` WHERE 
              `direction` = "3" 
              AND `reciever_id` = 0 
              AND `status`="1" 
              AND `has_providers` = "1" 
                  AND `reserved_bebs` = 0 
                  AND `maximum_cost` > 0 
                  AND `count_numbers`>0 
                  AND (`app_mobile_numbers`>0 OR `sms_mobile_numbers`>0) 
                  AND (`cron_hash`="" OR `cron_hash` IS NULL) ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1);

    SET @sql_text = concat('UPDATE `messages_temp` SET `cron_hash` = "',@cronHashVar,'",`last_process` = "',@lastProccess,'",`cron_name` = "providerDestributor" WHERE id = @targetiDS AND (cron_hash="" OR cron_hash IS NULL)');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM messages_temp WHERE cron_hash=@cronHashVar;


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

this should update only one record but it always updating two records once i add the last query

```
'SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM messages_temp WHERE cron_hash=@cronHashVar;
```

can you please help i need once record only to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why *I* would expect the stored procedure to only update one row.  If I assumed that `messages_temp(id)` were a primary key (or at least unique), then that assumption would be correct.  The fact that your query updates multiple rows suggests that this is not true.

If you want only one row updated, then add `limit 1` to the end of the `update`statement.

Comment: I add limit 1 at the end of the update statement it's still updating 2 records if i call the procedure once, but if you remove the following query (SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM messages_temp WHERE cron_hash=@cronHashVar;) it will update once record, why?

Comment: the id is primary, so one record only should be apdated by the call of the procedure, limit after update is there

Comment: @user2876390 . . . If `id` is unique, then at most only one row could be updated in that statement.  Why do you think there are multiple rows being updated?

Answer (score 0):

The select for ids is a condition of the update sentence. Use as it.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE providerDistributor(
    IN cronHash VARCHAR(255),
    IN lastProccess DATETIME 
)
BEGIN
    SET @cronHashVar = cronHash;
    SET @lastProccess = lastProccess;
    UPDATE 
        `messages_temp`
    SET
        `cron_hash`    = "@cronHashVar",
        `last_process` = "@lastProccess",
        `cron_name`    = "providerDestributor"
    WHERE
        `direction`         = "3" 
        AND `reciever_id`   = 0 
        AND `status`        = "1" 
        AND `has_providers` = "1" 
        AND `reserved_bebs` = 0 
        AND `maximum_cost`  > 0 
        AND `count_numbers` > 0 
        AND ( `app_mobile_numbers` > 0 OR `sms_mobile_numbers` > 0 ) 
        AND ( `cron_hash` = "" OR `cron_hash` IS NULL );
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Note: Maybe the value assigned to `cron_name = "providerDestributor"` is `"providerDistributor"`.

Comment: I need one record to be updated in one call, and return the updated records in the same procedure
if i add add any query after the update query then two records will be updated instead of one record.
I test it so many times but still the same